# Launch native camera app with option to capture either video or image

Tags: android, camera

I've written an app before where I open the native camera app to capture an image like this:

`Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);`

Or, like this for capturing video:

`Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);`

But is there a way to open the native camera app with the option to capture *either* video or an image? I'd like to open to the image given below, where the user can swipe to access the side-menu and change their input type.

[image: Image Below]

I've tried searching, but no results have come up yet. I'm not sure if there is a way to do this without writing a custom camera implementation, which I'd like to avoid for now.

If this is possible, how can I do it? And how could I go about recognizing what media type the user has chosen once the capture is complete (in `onActivityResult`, probably)?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently As specified by you there are 2 intents for capturing image and video i.e. `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` & `MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE`[link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intents).

For intially I was also thinking **startActivityForResult (Intent intent, int requestCode, Bundle options)**, Here **options** param was used to give the extras for the external applications but we can only specify some animations not the values as specified [link1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent,%20android.os.Bundle)) & [link2](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityOptions.html).

**Solution**

I would rather suggest you to go for the custom app with options as you like rather than the restrictions given by the existing camera app.